# A question on the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $a_n = 1 / \log_2(n)$ and $b_n = \log_2(n)$. Let $x \in (0,1)$ and consider the partial sum
\begin{equation}
S_n = a_n \sum_{i = 2}^n \frac{1}{i^{a_n}} \big(1 - (1-x)^{b_n}\big)^i.
\end{equation}
The question is: does it exists a $\delta \in (0,1)$, which does not depend on $n$, such that for any fixed $x \in (0,\delta)$, it holds that 
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n < \infty ? 
\end{equation}
From numerical calculations using Matlab, it seems that such a delta exists. But I am not able to give a proof of this claim. If I replace the term $1 - (1-x)^{b_n}$ with, e.g., $0.99$, then the partial sum
\begin{equation}
S_n ' = a_n \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i^{a_n}} 0.99^i
\end{equation}
does converge to a finite value. Now the point is that $1 - (1-x)^{b_n}$ would converge "slowly" to $1$ for a fixed $x \in (0,1)$, since on the exponent $b_n = \log_2(n)$, so that likely the original partial sum would also converge. I am also trying to compare, for each $i$ in the summation,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{i^{a_n}} \big(1 - (1-x)^{b_n}\big)^i \text{ with } \frac{1}{i}.
\end{equation}
If the two are "comparable" for small $x$, then $S_n$ essentially is $a_n \sum_{i=3}^n 1/i$, which is bounded. Anyone has an idea? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is not true.

Note that $(1 - (1-x)^{\log(n)}) = \left(1 - 2^{\log(1-x) \log(n)}\right) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^c} \right)$, where $ c =-\log(1-x) > 0$, for every $x \in (0,1)$.

Then, for every $i = 1, \ldots, n^c$, we get $(1 - (1-x)^{b_n})^i \geq \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^c} \right)^{n^c} $ which converge to $e$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

To conclude,

\begin{eqnarray}
S_n &=& a_n \sum_{i = 2}^n \frac{1}{i^{a_n}} \big(1 - (1-x)^{b_n}\big)^i \\ &\geq& a_n \sum_{i = 2}^{n^c} \frac{1}{i^{a_n}} \big(1 - (1-x)^{b_n}\big)^i \\
&\geq& 
\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^c}\right)^{n^c} \left[ a_n \sum_{i = 2}^{n^c} \frac{1}{i^{a_n}}\right]\\ &\geq& \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^c}\right)^{n^c} \int_2^{n^c} \frac{a_n}{x^{a_n}} dx  ~~ \geq ~~ \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^c}\right)^{n^c} a_n \left(n^{c(1 - a_n)} - 1/2 \right) \longrightarrow \infty.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I think in your definition of $c$, it is in $(0,1)$ as long as $x$ is small enough. So in fact $(1 - 1 / n^c)^n$ converges to $0$. No?

Comment: You are right, i make a mistake! But we don't need to sum to $n$, we can sum only to $n^c$ which is enough.